# Simple Oracle query using JDBI from DropWizard doesn't execute/return result

Tags: java, oracle, dropwizard, jdbi

I have a DropWizard project with 2 database connections: one MySql and one Oracle (v11). The MySql connection and queries work just fine. I'm not getting any data from my Oracle queries and there are no errors in my logs.

My DOA looks like this:

```
public interface DummyDao {

    @SqlQuery(
            "select prod_sku, initial_qty, current_qty" +
            " from prod_detail" +
            " where prod_sku = :skuNumber")
    @Mapper(DummyMapper.class)
    Dummy getSku(@Bind("skuNumber") String skuNumber);

}
```

My mapper looks like this. When I added log statements to the mapper, I was able to verify it is never called.

```
public class DummyMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Dummy> {

    public Dummy map(int index, ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx)
            throws SQLException {

        return new Dummy(
            r.getString("prod_sku"),
            r.getLong("initial_qty"),
            r.getLong("current_qty"));

    }

}
```

The DAO is being initialized in my application's run method via the following code:

```
public class ProductServiceApplication extends Application<ProductServiceConfiguration> {

    DataSource sb_ds;
    DBI sb_dbi;
    DummyDao dummyDao;

    @Override
    public void run(
            final ProductServiceConfiguration configuration,
            final Environment environment) {

        sb_ds = configuration.getSbliveDataSourceFactory()
                .build(environment.metrics(), "sblive");
        sb_dbi = new DBI(sb_ds);
        dummyDao = sb_dbi.onDemand(DummyDao.class);

    }

}
```

In order to verify there's nothing wrong with my connection, I temporarily added the following code to my run method and it returns the expected result:

```
 try (Handle h = sb_dbi.open()) {
     List<Map<String,Object>> result =
         h.select("select initial_qty, current_qty from prod_detail where prod_sku = '10501034520008'");
     System.out.println("bootstrap: " + result.toString());
 }
```

Executing my DAO's getSku method with the same parameter returns null.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to measures I can take to figure out what's causing this? I tried to debug it, but I simply don't know enough about JDBI internals to make any sense of what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem is that the column associated with the bind variable is defined as CHAR(20) -- not VARCHAR(20) -- and the actual parameter value has a length of 14. When I execute the statement directly (using the handle or from SqlDeveloper), it works fine. But when using a prepared statement and bind variables, it's broken.

Padding the parameter out to 20 characters resolves the issue.